# Sending Email with iCloud in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, icloud, smtplib

I am trying to send some emails from an iCloud email address using the code below:

```
import smtplib


def main():
    smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.me.com', 587)
    smtp_obj.starttls()
    smtp_obj.login('user@icloud.com', 'password')

    pairs = {'name_1': 'email_1@gmail.com', 'name_2': 'email_2@gmail.com'}

    try:
        for name in pairs.keys():
            body = 'hi {}'.format(name)
            print('Sending email to {}...'.format(name))
            send_status = smtp_obj.sendmail(smtp_obj.user, pairs.get(name), body)

            if send_status != {}:
                print('There was a problem sending mail to {}.\n{}'.format(name, send_status))
    except smtplib.SMTPDataError:
        print('Sending email to {} failed.'.format(name))
    finally:
        smtp_obj.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, when I run this, I only get an SMTPDataError, saying,

```
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, b'5.7.0 From address is not one of your addresses')
```

I've tried hardcoding different addresses. When I use my address, I get this. When I use an address I know to be wrong, the error message also prints out the invalid email (which this account would have no way to access - for instance, listing an un-logged-into gmail address to see what happens).

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn'it related to the Email used to send e-mails ?

Comment: Yes, the error is coming in the line that uses "sendmail." However, I'm using the exact same email with which I logged in, and that line of code did fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem. As it turns out, the "from" and "to" addresses must be provided as part of the message body for icloud to send the email.

The code segment I was missing is the following:

```
try:
    for name in pairs.keys():
        msg = ('From: {}\r\nTo: {}\r\n\r\nHi, {}'.format(smtp_obj.user,
                                                         pairs.get(name),
                                                         name))

        print('Sending email to {} at {}...'.format(name, pairs.get(name)))

        send_status = smtp_obj.sendmail(from_addr=smtp_obj.user,
                                        to_addrs=pairs.get(name),
                                        msg=msg)

        if send_status != {}:
            print('There was a problem sending mail to {}.\n{}'.format(name, send_status))
finally:
    smtp_obj.quit()
```

Comment: I just found this after wasting two hours trying to troubleshoot this problem! I'm just curious, how did you figure this out?

Comment: I think it was when I looked up the kwargs for `sendmail` it became obvious that it needed some particular format. It's actually even more clear to use `EmailMessage` and `Address` (`from email.headerregistry import Address` and 
`from email.message import EmailMessage`). I hope this helps. And if you liked the question and/or answer, the upvotes always help :)

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use the standard library's [`email` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) to construct the e-mail with the correct headers, which sidesteps the issue.

```py
import email.message
import smtplib


smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.me.com', 587)
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login('myuser@icloud.com', 'mypassword')

message = email.message.EmailMessage()
message.set_content('Hello, world!')
message['Subject'] = 'Test message'
message['From'] = 'myuser@icloud.com'
message['To'] = 'myuser@icloud.com'

try:
    errs = smtp.send_message(message)
    if errs:
        raise smtplib.SMTPException(f'Failures: {errs}')
finally:
    smtp.quit()
```